# How to test Socket.io and Express on a DOMAIN

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to run Node.js on a domain that I do NOT own (basically a snadbox), I figured the problem is that socket.io and express are not running. The domain I have access to upload files to is https://'Domain'.com/MyID (domain is in quotes so it doesn't make a link here) 
The code shown is what runs perfectly on localhost NOT ON A DOMAIN, this is my first experience with node thus I do not know what to do after weeks of videos that only show it running on localhost.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log("Server started.");
```

So I found this

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

And I'm wandering if I can set hostname to a domain directory (directory being my access to edit /MyID)

Before edit:

I tried changing the requirements in the code above but that did absolutely nothing

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('https://'example'.com/MyID').Server(app);

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log("Server started.");
```

Please help me I do not know what to do.

Comment: What socket.io code? If your issue is looking for the domain, most sandboxes will set it in env as with port etc

Comment: what are you trying to do with `require('https://'example'.com/MyID')`?

Comment: I do not know what env is, also I just tried editing it to see if it does anything. I have no idea how it works on localhost or what it does and used this tutorial to do this,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfSwUOBL1YQ&list=PLcIaPHraYF7k4FbeGIDY-1mZZdjTu9QyL